# Find all solutions ${x_1,x_2,...,x_n}$ of the equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Find all solutions ${x_1,x_2,...,x_n}$ of the equation

$$1+\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{x_1+1}{(x_1)(x_2)}+\frac{(x_1+1)(x_2+1)}{(x_1)(x_2)(x_3)}+...+\frac{(x_1+1)...(x_{n-1}+1)}{(x_1)(x_2)...(x_n)}=0$$

I didnt make that much progress with this problem but here are some observations i made:

$x_1 \neq 0$, so i thought about making $x_1=-1$ which seems to help but then it wouldnt really matter what the rest of the $x_2, x_3...x_n $ values are. So i guess my answer would be wrong

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=1$ this is just $$\frac{x_1+1}{x_1}=0\;,$$ which of course has the solution $x_1=-1$. For $n=2$ it’s

$$\frac{x_1x_2+x_2+x_1+1}{x_1x_2}=\frac{(x_1+1)(x_2+1)}{x_1x_2}\;,$$

with solutions $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=-1$. For $n=3$ it’s

$$\frac{x_1x_2x_3+x_2x_3+x_3(x_1+1)+(x_1+1)(x_2+2)}{x_1x_2x_3}\;,$$

which simplifies to

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(x_1x_2+x_2+x_1+1)x_3+(x_1+1)(x_2+1)}{x_1x_2x_3}&=\frac{(x_1+1)(x_2+2)x_3+(x_1+1)(x_2+1)}{x_1x_2x_3}\\
&=\frac{(x_1+1)(x_2+1)(x_3+1)}{x_1x_2x_3}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so that $x_1=-1$ or $x_2=-1$ or $x_3=-1$. At this point you should be able to conjecture a nice form of the expression for arbitrary $n\ge 1$ and prove it by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is partially correct: $x_1=-1$ and $x_2,\ldots,x_n$ can be anything.  But there are other solutions too.

**Hint**.  The LHS can be factorised as
$$\Bigl(1+\frac1{x_1}\Bigr)\Bigl(1+\frac1{x_2}\Bigr)\cdots
  \Bigl(1+\frac1{x_n}\Bigr)\ .$$